# need to define all available constructor forms in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class like this:

```
class A{
    private:
        init(const std::string& s=""){/*do something*/}
    public:
        A(){init();}
        A(const A&){init();}
        A(const std::string& s){init(s);}
};
```

Does it cover all the forms that constructors may be called?

What I am trying to do is, **any** object creation must call the `init()` function at first i.e I need to define all the constructors that may be called implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Only defined constructors can be called, right? So I think this isn't really a big problem.

Comment: Just for your information, the last constructor (`A(const A&, const std::string s)`) is not a copy-constructor. It doesn't really make much sense to me (at least not without more context).

Comment: You're also missing a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Comment: Lastly, the default constructor is not needed if you add a default value for the string argument in the third variant you show.

Comment: Note that you could use delegating constructirs instead of the `init()` function.

Comment: @J3soon I think the point is that the compiler might synthesize one that wouldn't call `init()`. But in this case, it won't.

Comment: Your `const std::string` arguments are premature pessimization.  They pointlessly force your code to be slower.  I suspect that is because you do not understand `const` and argument passing in C++ and move semantics and references vs values.

Comment: @Yakk and your suggestion?

Comment: @Jahid Learn about references, move semantics and argument passing in C++?  Or you mean in this case?  Get rid of the `const`, and `move` when calling `init` (this presumes that `init` stores said string somewhere within it).  Alternatively, make all of your `const std::string`s references to `const std::string`s.

Comment: @Yakk `const std::string` was a typo. I meant to say `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A(const A&)
```

once you have defined `A(A const&)` the compiler will not synthesize any other constructors.  The only callable constructors will be the ones you declare.

The same is true of `A(A&&)`, as an aside.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a slight misunderstanding of C++ constructors.

Under specific circumstances classes have certain constructors *implicitly declared with defaulted definitions*. To avoid constructors that don't call your `init()` function does not require you to declare these constructors. You can instead follow certain rules that prevent them from being implicitly declared, or you can define some in-class initialization which ensures that the default definitions do the extra initialization you want.

The default constructor is only implicitly declared as defaulted if there are no user-declared constructors.

A copy constructor is only implicitly declared as defaulted if there are no user-declared move constructors or move-assignment operators (and of course no user-declared copy constructor).

A move constructor is only implicitly declared if there are no user-declared copy constructors, copy assignment operators, move constructors, move assignment operators, or destructors (and if the default definition for a move constructor would be valid).

So you could ensure that object construction always calls your `init()` function by declaring some subset of members that suppresses implicit declarations of any other constructors.

([This](http://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014) slideshow has a handy reference on the conditions for implicit declarations of the special member functions.)

---

Following the above rules: Declaring this copy constructor, for example, suppresses the default constructor, the move constructor, and the implicitly declared copy constructor. This therefore ensures that no objects of this class can be constructed without calling the `init()` member function.

```
struct S {
  S(S const &) { init(); }
  void init() {}
};
```

---

You can also simply use C++11 in-class initialization, which executes even in default definitions, to ensure `init()` is called for all construction.

```
struct S {
  int x = init();

  int init() { return 10; }

  // ... whatever constructors you want to define
};
```

So long as your user-declared constructors don't explicitly initialize `x`, then all the constructors, both user-declared and implicitly declared, will call `init()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hack that does this, but it isn't the most clear on intent.

```
class A{
private:
    bool init(...){...; return true; }
    bool initialized = init(...);

public:
    // your constructors. 
};
```

Do keep in mind that the parameters to init have not to be dependent on the parameters of the constructor.

Comment: I need the constructor part not the `init()`

Comment: With this, it doesn't matter what is in the constructors, init will be called.

Comment: I can't use it though, inits args depend on args of constructors

Answer (score 1):

For this case, it *might* be worth considering using implementation inheritance:

```
class base { 
protected:
    base(std::string const &s="") { /* equivalent of your `init` */ }

    // Or possibly use overloading:
    // base() { /* whatever */ }
    // base(std::string const &) { /* whatever */ }
};

class A : public base { 
    A(const std::string& s) : base(s) {}
    A(const A&, const std::string& s) : base(s) {}
};
```

Since `A` is derived from `base`, every ctor for `A` *must* invoke `base`'s constructor. If you don't use the member initializer list to pass a parameter, it'll be invoked automatically with the default parameter--but creating an `A` without invoking the `base` ctor is essentially impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better define the move constructor A(A&&), I'm not sure about the policies on automatically generate constructor of different compilers, though C++11 has the explicit definition.

[see more info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx)